# Pasar de switch a if else en programación C

Tags: c

Alguien podría transformar esta parte de mi código que está usando switch/case a if/else? Es un programa que hace de calculadora con noatación polonesa inversa. No he insertado aquí todo el código, solo la parte que necesito cambiar, pues todo lo demás funciona pero esto no. Es que lo habia hecho usando switch case (me funcionaba) pero ahora el profesor nos ha dicho que tiene que ser con el if y cuando intenté cambiarlo, no funcionaba. Si alguien pudiera hacerlo, me iria muy bien. Gracias. (Pd:Es un porgrama de C, no C++)

```
 while ((caracter = asignacio(calculs)) != EOF) {
              switch (caracter) {

            case '0': 
                mat[m][0]=0;
                mat[m][1]=atof(calculs);
            empila(atof(calculs));
            m++;
                break;
            case 'e':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=e;
            empila(e);
            m++;
                break;
            case 'p':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=pi;
            empila(pi);
            m++;
                break;
            case 'a':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=auri;
            empila(auri);
            m++;
                break;
            case 'u':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=euler;
            empila(euler);
            m++;
                break;
            case 'g':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=af;
            empila(af);
            m++;
                break;
            case 'd':
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=df;
            empila(df);
            m++;
                break;
            case '+':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=0;
            op1=desempila();
            op2 = desempila();
            empila(op2 + op1);
            m++;
                break;
            case '-':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=1;
            op1=desempila();
            op2 = desempila();
            empila(op2 - op1);
            m++;
                break;
            case '*':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=2;
            op1=desempila();
            op2 = desempila();
            empila(op2 * op1);
            m++;
                break;
            case '/':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=3;
            op1=desempila();
            op2 = desempila();
            if (op1 == 0.0)
               printf("ERROR: S'esta dividint per zero\n");
            else{
                 empila(op2 / op1);
                m++;
            }
                break;
            case '^':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=4;
            op1=desempila();
            op2 = desempila();
            empila(poten(op2,op1));
            m++;
                break;
            case 'f':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=5;
            op1=desempila();
            empila(factorial(op1));
                break;
            case 'n':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=6;
            op1=desempila();
            op2=desempila();
            empila(op2*(1/poten(10, op1)));
            m++;
                break;
            case 'q':
                op1=desempila();
                if(op1<0){
                    printf("Error: No es pot fer l'arrel d'un numero negatiu\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                 mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=7;
                empila(sqrt(op1));
                m++;
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=8;
                op1=desempila();
                empila(sin(op1));
                m++;
                break;
            case 'c':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=9;
                op1=desempila();
                empila(cos(op1));
                m++;
                break;
            case 't':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=10;
                op1=desempila();
                empila(tan(op1));
                m++;
                break;
            case 'x':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=11;
                op1=desempila();
                empila(exp(op1));
                m++;
                 break;
            case 'l':
                mat[m][0]=2;
                mat[m][1]=12;
                op1=desempila();
                empila(log(op1));
                m++;
                break;
            case 'i':
                for(int i=0; i<148; i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=1;j++) {
            printf("%5.2lf\t", mat[i][j]);}
            printf("\n");}
            empila(0);
               break;
           case fi:
            r=desempila();
            printf("\nResposta: %.10g\n\n", r);
             mat[m][0]=0;
            mat[m][1]=r;
            m++;

            printf("------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            printf("Si vols, pots seguir introduint operacions (o prem \"ctrl+C\" per finalitzar i \"enter\" per tancar la consola):\n\n");
            break;
            default:
            printf("\nERROR: No s'ha reconegut algun dels caracters. Revisa la llista de notacio.\n");
            break;


        }
        }
```

Comment: Que error te daba el if cuando intentabas hacerlo por ti mismo? En este sitio no hacemos el trabajo por ti. Esto es por tu bien, ya que si lo hacemos por ti no aprenderás. Lectura recomendada: [Te he votado negativamente porque solicitas directamente que alguien haga tu trabajo/tarea escolar (sin demostrar ningún esfuerzo por resolverla por ti mismo).](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/4320#4320)

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que es `fi`? Lo usas en el útlimo `case`.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que este ejercicio lo mandará para que cojáis algo de soltura con los bucles y demás.

En realidad la sentencia switch-case no es más que una forma de hacer una cadena de if-else. Deberás poner un "if" por cada "case" que tienes. Te recomiendo además que para los "case" utilices la intrucción "else if", ya que te hará ahorrar tiempo al no tener que leer todas las instrucciones y será una forma más fiel de recrear el switch-case. Recuerda además que el caso "default" es equivalente a un "else".

El código se quedaría algo así:

```
 while ((caracter = asignacio(calculs)) != EOF) 
 {
      if(caracter == '0') {
          mat[m][0]=0;
          mat[m][1]=atof(calculs);
          empila(atof(calculs));
          m++;
      }
      else if ( caracter == 'e') {
      // código de "case 'e'"
      }
      else if (caracter == 'p') {
      // código de "case 'p'"
      }
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      else if (caracter == 'fi') {
      // código de "case 'fi'"
      }
      else { // Esto es equivalente al 'default'
         printf("\nERROR: No s'ha reconegut algun dels caracters. Revisa la llista de notacio.\n");
      }
} // end while
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: "*la sentencia switch-case no es más que una forma de hacer
una cadena de if-else*". El switch genera un jump table, no
un if-else.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero lo decía por ‘simplificar’ un poco la idea porque se nota que el publicador de este post está empezando. Por eso hice algo de hincapié en las instrucciones ‘else if’, ya que si esta devuelve ‘true’ no valora el resto de condiciones, es decir, igual que el ‘switch-case’.

Comment: *...no valora el resto de condiciones, es decir, igual que el ‘switch-case’.* Eso sólo ocurre si usas la sentencia `break` dentro de una etiqueta `case`, pero si no la usas, se siguen evaluando el resto de expresiones con etiqueta, hasta una instrucción `break` o hasta que se alcance el final de la instrucción `switch`. A veces simplificar una idea no es lo mejor. Explicar el concepto con detalle sería más enriquecedor. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, esta comparación: `caracter == 'fi'`. No veo dónde `'fi'` es **un carácter**. Desde siempre un carácter ocupa 1 byte (8 bits), por lo tanto, quitando el hecho de que sintácticamente `'fi'` no es válido en C (produce un overflow al intentar convertir la expresión de la derecha en un tipo `char`), no es correcta la comparación de 1 carácter con algo que no es un carácter. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué se tendría que cambiar un switch por un if else anidado. Lo que se puede hacer es agrupar los case entre llaves.

Usando la estructura `switch` y con llaves sería así

```
 while ((caracter = asignacio(calculs)) != EOF) {
              switch (caracter) {

            case '0':
                {
                mat[m][0]=0;
                mat[m][1]=atof(calculs);
                empila(atof(calculs));
                m++;
                }
                break;
            case 'e':
                {
                mat[m][0]=1;
                mat[m][1]=e;
                empila(e);
                m++;
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
            ...
            ...
```

Comment: Por favor, no respondas varias veces. Edita tu respuesta original y añade ahí lo que necesites

Comment: En cualquier caso, lo dicho en tu otra respuesta. Esto **no sirve** porque el OP ya se ha encargado de decir que **no se puede** usar `switch`

Comment: Esas llaves simplemente crean un ámbito para cada `case`. Este ámbito te permitiría crear variables locales en cada `case` (sin esas llaves el compilador se quejaría ya que se podrían provocar inconsistencias). Dicho de otra forma, si no vas a declarar variables locales en un `case`, esas llaves **no aportan absolutamente nada**

Answer (score 0):

```
Si lo haces con if y else if, quedaria de esta manera, tu mismo codigo pero con if y else if. Espero te sirva.

while ((caracter = asignacio(calculs)) != EOF) {
if(caracter == '0'){ 
    mat[m][0]=0;
    mat[m][1]=atof(calculs);
    empila(atof(calculs));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'e'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=e;
    empila(e);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'p'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=pi;
    empila(pi);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'a'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=auri;
    empila(auri);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'u'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=euler;
    empila(euler);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'g'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=af;
    empila(af);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'd'){
    mat[m][0]=1;
    mat[m][1]=df;
    empila(df);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == '+'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=0;
    op1=desempila();
    op2 = desempila();
    empila(op2 + op1);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == '-'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=1;
    op1=desempila();
    op2 = desempila();
    empila(op2 - op1);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == '*'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=2;
    op1=desempila();
    op2 = desempila();
    empila(op2 * op1);
    m++;
}else if(caracter == '/'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=3;
    op1=desempila();
    op2 = desempila();
    if (op1 == 0.0)
        printf("ERROR: S'esta dividint per zero\n");
    else{
        empila(op2 / op1);
        m++;
    }
}else if(caracter == '^'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=4;
    op1=desempila();
    op2 = desempila();
    empila(poten(op2,op1));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'f'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=5;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(factorial(op1));
}else if(caracter == 'n'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=6;
    op1=desempila();
    op2=desempila();
    empila(op2*(1/poten(10, op1)));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'q'){
    op1=desempila();
    if(op1<0){
        printf("Error: No es pot fer l'arrel d'un numero negatiu\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        mat[m][0]=2;
        mat[m][1]=7;
        empila(sqrt(op1));
        m++;
    }
}else if(caracter == 's'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=8;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(sin(op1));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'c'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=9;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(cos(op1));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 't'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=10;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(tan(op1));
    m++;
else if(caracter == 'x'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=11;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(exp(op1));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'l'){
    mat[m][0]=2;
    mat[m][1]=12;
    op1=desempila();
    empila(log(op1));
    m++;
}else if(caracter == 'i'){
    for(int i=0; i<148; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<=1;j++) {
            printf("%5.2lf\t", mat[i][j]);}
        printf("\n");}
    empila(0);
}else if(caracter == 'fi'){
    r=desempila();
    printf("\nResposta: %.10g\n\n", r);
    mat[m][0]=0;
    mat[m][1]=r;
    m++;
    
    printf("------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Si vols, pots seguir introduint operacions (o prem \"ctrl+C\" per finalitzar i \"enter\" per tancar la consola):\n\n");
}else{

    printf("\nERROR: No s'ha reconegut algun dels caracters. Revisa la llista de notacio.\n");
}
```

}